# asp.net empty textbox help needed

Tags: c#, asp.net

I created a basic web form application where user enters their name, age and gender in to different textboxes, when that is done they press submit button which then produces the result into a label. The problem I'm having is if no text is entered and someone presses submit the label still says

> hello {}  i am   {}    years old and im {}

The `{}` are where the name, age and gender appears...

How do I get around this? I know I can put if statement and check to see if all textboxes are not null but is there an efficient or quicker way?

here is the field validatiors i used:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="textbox1" ErrorMessage="Name required"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

<asp:TextBox ID="txtage" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ControlToValidate="textbox2" ErrorMessage="Input age"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

<asp:TextBox ID="txtnumber" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ControlToValidate="textbox3" ErrorMessage="input gender"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Comment: Please post your code :)

Comment: add `<asp:RequiredFieldValidator />`s to your page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator.aspx

Comment: Its best to use `if(textbox.value == string.Empty){ label1.text = "Required Field"} else{label2.text = textbox.value};`

Comment: if you're just starting you should 'just start' with ASP.NET MVC.  It's great

Comment: code is:
string name,age,gender;

name = textbox1.Text;
age=textbox2.Text;
gender= textbox3.text;

lblresult= "Hello " + name + " I am " + age + "years old and im a " + gender;

Comment: `ControlToValidate="textbox1"` --> control to validate should be the id of the control u want to validate - txtname. Similarly for other text boxes: txtage, txtnumber

Answer (score 0):

you can do server side C# validation on click event

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox1.text))
{
   return;     
}
```

or you can use asp.net validation

```
<asp:TextBox ID="textbox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
                ErrorMessage="Please Enter Name" ControlToValidate="textbox1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Comment: i already have field validators on the textboxes that i want to validate but the problem is even though it is blank the resultlabel produces text.

Comment: Even though all textboxes are blank and i press submit the result label will say "Hello  {}   i am {}      years old and i am   {}     " {} gaps is where textbox data should appear

Comment: string name,age,gender; name = textbox1.Text; age=textbox2.Text; gender= textbox3.text; lblresult= "Hello " + name + " I am " + age + "years old and im a " + gender;

Comment: c# code is above your comment and have added the asp.net code of the fieldvalidators. hope you can help me now

Comment: Look your RequiredFieldValidator  ControlToValidate="textbox1" property it has wrong id of text box .
Replace with below
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtname" ErrorMessage="Name required"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

Comment: have changed it but still the same problem happens... if i load web application and press submit then the lblresult still produces "Hello {} i am {} years old and i am {} " {} gaps is where textbox data should appear" but the field validators are working because even though i press submit and lblresult produces text next to textbox1 the error message appears..
I just want to know how to stop the lblresult from appearing if no text enetered into any box? is there any other way as the only way i can think of is using if(textbox1.text=string.empty) and use the same for other textboxes?

Comment: check your id & lablel name. now only guess is miss spelling.

Answer (score 0):

Put the following in your botton click event...

```
If (!string.isnullorempty(NameTextBox.Text) && ! string.isnullorempty(AgeTextBox.Text) && !string.isnullorempty(GenderTextBox.Text)
{
Label1.Text = string.Format("hello {0} I am {1} years old and I'm {2}", NameTextBox.Text, AgeTextBox.Text, GenderTextBox.Text);
}
Else
{
Label1.Text = string.empty;
}
```

Also as previously mentioned the "controltovalidate" attribute of your requiredfieldvalidators should be the Id of the textbox/field you wish to validate...

Hope this helps